# Apache: If url starts with string, grant access otherwise use IP whitelisting

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

In Apache 2.4, i'm trying to use IP whitelisting on my entire site, expect some specific URL patterns:

- `/wp-json/hl/v1/*`
- `/hl/images/*`

Note: I've currently disabled my own IP for testing.
When I try to access any URL I get a 403, but really I should only get a 403 outside aforementioned URL patterns.

Currently my VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...other configs

    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/wp-json/hl/v1/.*$#">
            Require all granted
    </If>

    <ElseIf "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/hl/images/.*$#">
            Require all granted
    </ElseIf>

    <Else>
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip ::1
            Require ip 127.0.0.1
            Require ip [MY_IP]
        </RequireAny>
    </Else>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas are welcome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: @anubhava Updated original question, but I get 403's across the entire site, where I should be able to call the beforementioned URL patterns regarding of my IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` and combine `Elseif` into `If` using regex alternation:

```bash
    <If "%{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#^/(wp-json/hl/v1|hl/images)/#">
            Require all granted
    </If>
    <Else>
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip ::1
            Require ip 127.0.0.1
            Require ip [MY_IP]
        </RequireAny>
    </Else>
```

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. When I debug this it falls into the "<Else>" block and validating each of the listed IPs. EDIT: This seems to work, my problem is in an .htaccess file somewhere!